# Error : minimum supported gradle version is 4.6 in android studio 3.0.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I want to use forcefully 4.4 gradle version

Is there any solution for that? I'm searching solution from long but couldn't able to find
it

> Minimum supported Gradle version is 4.6. The current version is 4.4. 
>   Please fix the project's Gradle settings. Fix Gradle wrapper and
>   re-import project Gradle settings

*gradle-wrapper.properties*

```
#Mon Sep 03 10:52:24 IST 2018
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

*build.gradle*

```
 dependencies {
          classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-beta05"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

*Project structure dialog*

[image]

Comment: what is your gradle android plugin version ?

Comment: *I want use forcefully 4.4 gradle version*.... is there any specific reason for this?

Comment: well how about downgrading your android studio then ?. But why exactly you want to use the old version :) ?

Comment: I'm developing a module app with 4.6 but another team developer has 4.4

Comment: @KishoreJethava you will run into compatibility issues later so why not ask him to upgrade it to latest version :). or you can downgrade your android studio

Comment: @Umair I have downgraded still showing error

Comment: @Qasim see updated question

Comment: @KishoreJethava try using the normal verison of gradle not the beta one like this:

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'`

Comment: *another team developer has 4.4* - tell him to update. You're just wasting time here

Comment: @All upgrading is not a solution for me

Comment: @KishoreJethava can you try with android grade plugin 3.1.0 ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The minimum supported version of android plugin for Gradle `3.2.0+` requires Gradle version `4.6` or higher. If you want to use Gradle version `4.4`, you have to downgrade your android plugin to `3.1.0`.

For detail compatibility information about plugin and gradle versions, see this https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin

Comment: You also need to [decrement](https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage/issues/115#issuecomment-498016892) the version of `classpath com.android.tools.build:gradle` in `build.gradle`